# Restrict AWS EC2 Instance Profile to only use KMS key on EBS volumes with certain tags

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam, amazon-kms

I have a KMS CMK that is used by instances to encrypt/decrypt the underlying EBS volumes. I wanted to make the key policy more restrictive to only allow use of the key on volumes with a certain tag, so I did the following (Terraform):

```
  statement {
    sid    = "Allow use of the key by instance role
    effect = "Allow"
    actions = [
      "kms:Encrypt",
      "kms:Decrypt",
      "kms:ReEncrypt*",
      "kms:GenerateDataKey*",
      "kms:DescribeKey",
      "kms:CreateGrant",
      "kms:ListGrants",
      "kms:RevokeGrant"
    ]
    resources = ["arn:aws:ebs::*"]
    principals {
      type = "AWS"
      identifiers = [
        "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT_ID:role/my_instance_role"
      ]
    }
    condition {
      test     = "StringEquals"
      variable = "aws:ResourceTag/name"
      values = [
        "my-volume"
      ]
    }
  }
```

However, KMS doesn't allow `aws:ResourceTag` conditions in key policies. It has to be enforced on the IAM policy (caller) side that is attached to the instance role. Would this be the correct method to only allow the use of the key if the EBS volume has the `my-volume` tag:

```
{
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": [
        "kms:Encrypt",
        "kms:Decrypt",
        "kms:ReEncrypt*",
        "kms:GenerateDataKey*",
        "kms:DescribeKey",
        "kms:CreateGrant",
        "kms:ListGrants",
        "kms:RevokeGrant"
    ],
    "Resource": "arn:aws:kms:us-east-1:ACCOUNT_ID:key/KMS_KEY_ID",
    "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
            "aws:ResourceTag/name": "my-volume"
        }
    }
}

The condition being the tag of my EBS volumes.
```

Comment: That would grant access to the principal to only use the KMS key with the tag `my-volume` (which is redundant selection, as in this case as you've already specified the key with the key ID) - it wouldn't act on the tags of the EBS volume.

Comment: Yeah, I would need a separate policy with kms actions with the resource being the ebs volumes with the tag conditions, correct?